# Adding latex custom component to javafx SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, latex, scenebuilder

I would like to make a simple component that I can use inside the scene builder which will show some LaTeX formula. I would like to point that I am quite new to this whole scenebuilder and javafx stuff, which I only learnt in the last few days.

So far, trying to add LaTeX to javafx, I found the solution of drawing on a canvas using `jlatexmath` and `FXGraphics2D` as follows:

```
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.*;

public class TexCanvas extends Canvas {

  private FXGraphics2D g2;

  private Box box;

  public TexCanvas(){}

  public void setFormula(String textFormula){
    GraphicsContext gc = getGraphicsContext2D();
    this.g2 = new FXGraphics2D(gc);
    this.g2.scale(50, 50);

    // create a formula
    TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula(textFormula);
    TeXIcon icon = formula.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 40);
    setWidth(1000);
    setHeight(1000);

    this.box = icon.getBox();
    box.draw(g2, 1, 2);
  }
}
```

This code works ok if I just add it directly to a javafx application. However,  the scene builder doesn't let me add this as a custom component. When I try to add the corresponding JAR file, it doesn't show that there are any components in it. For some reason, if I remove the `box.draw(g2,1,2)`
line, then I can add it. The JAR Analysis is

```
Not a Node: TexView/FXMLController.class
Exception for: TexView/TexCanvas.class java.io.IOException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/fx/FXGraphics2D
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:109)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:146)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:298)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:122)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/fx/FXGraphics2D
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:1638)
    at sun.reflect.misc.ConstructorUtil.getConstructors(ConstructorUtil.java:43)
    at javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory.scanForConstructorAnnotations(JavaFXBuilderFactory.java:217)
    at javafx.fxml.JavaFXBuilderFactory.getBuilder(JavaFXBuilderFactory.java:144)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1006)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:740)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2723)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(JarExplorer.java:105)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.fx.FXGraphics2D
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 18 more
```

This is my first problem. The second will be once I am able to add this component, how to set the formula from within the scene builder and if there is any way to actually see it already there and not just when I run the application.

I would appreciate any help in this matter, including if there are better ways to do this or maybe there are already libraries out there that do this.

Comment: When you add your jar to Scene Builder do you also include the required dependencies (`org.jfree...`)?